# VOA affine algebras

Tags: modules, conformal-field-theory

What is the difference between decomposition of tensor product 
of affine algebra VOA modules and their fusion product decomposition? 
I heard that for the former central extension parameter is additive,
while for the latter - it should be the same for two modules.
I would like to hear more explanations and comment.